# php - unlink with username and password?

Tags: php, apache

im new to php. I have a basic unlink php file which deletes a test.html. Using Apache httpserver

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('test.html', 'a');
fwrite($fh, '<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
fclose($fh);

unlink('test.html');
?>
```

So now how do i set a authentication method so that only a person with the correct username/password can access this file?

Comment: Any reason why you are opening a file, writing something to it and deleting the same right after?

Comment: @NullUserException I think it is just for an example.

Comment: oh i got this from the PHP manual website. just an example like @alex says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the protection in PHP, you'll need to place the unlink code inside a conditional block:

```
if(ok_to_delete())
{
    # unlink code
}
```

That function might look like this:

```
function ok_to_delete()
{
    # hash of your password
    if('d0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940' == sha1($_POST['delete_password']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the form:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="delete_password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Something" />
</form>
```

Putting `unlink()` in a conditional block prevents it from being arbitrarily executed by some other means (run from command-line, included in another file, etc.).

There are myriad ways to write the `ok_to_delete()` function, of course.  If you're curious you might poke around on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=authentication+system+in+php), or check out an open source project.

For a full-blown user auth system, there are a lot of concerns regarding security (using https, whether the form can be exploited, whether you can delete arbitrary files, whether passwords are secure, etc.).

For something simple like deleting some cache files, the example code may suffice.

#### Refs:

- [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
- [sha1()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)

Comment: what if i were to access the php file via http? im thinking the form might not be the solution for me. so is there anyway to put variables for checking via http? somethinglike http://localhost/delete.php?var=somethingsomething? then what would the code in delete.php be like?

Comment: The form and `$_POST` var will accomplish just that, via http (or https).  The reason you do not want to use the `$_GET` var and URL / query parameter as you described is that it could easily be read out of your browser history, or perhaps by a search engine, and anyone would be able to run the php script simply by visiting that URL.

Comment: ok. few questions tho. 1)where should i put the form code in? a phpfile?   2)im actually creating a iPad application (which doesn't save any history infomation )to URL http the file so i dont think it will be somewhat risky. So how should i code the php file then and what should i type in the browser

Comment: A full script might look like this:  http://pastebin.com/DzJGbA67  Still need to add in your delete code.  You'd simply view the script as a webpage to use it.

Comment: cool. but i would like to know how to do the URL/ query parameter method though.

Comment: `blah.php?param=value` is accessed via `$_GET['param']`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Apache, take a look at [htaccess passwords](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/). That's probably the simplest method.

Comment: Note that for unlink() to work, php needs to have sufficient permissions to write to the file.

Comment: ok so i have the .htaccess & .htpassword generated. i tried to access this file again by entering in browser http://localhost/test.php and it still works.?

Comment: Kenneth: Perhaps individual `.htaccess` files are disabled for your web directory? Do you have access to the apache configuration file?

Comment: yep i have full access to everything

Comment: oo ok somehow it works now , im getting an access forbiden !error 403 page. so what should i type in browser now to input the username and password

Comment: If it's set up properly, it should prompt you.